# Converting C++ union containing struct with bit field to java

Tags: java, c++

This is for an NES Emulator and I'm porting the code over from OLC's Code.
here's the code that I'm trying to convert:

```
union
    {
    struct
    {
        uint8_t unused : 5;
        uint8_t sprite_overflow : 1;
        uint8_t sprite_zero_hit : 1;
        uint8_t vertical_blank : 1;
    };
    uint8_t reg;
} status;
```

And heres my port:

```
short status; //unused:1-5 sprite_overflow:6 sprite_zero_hit:7 vertical blank:8

boolean getStatus(short b) { //b = 0x80
    return ((status&(0xFF-b))!=0)?true:false;
}

void setStatus(short b, boolean v) { //b = 0x80
    status&=(b-1);
    status|=(v):b?0x00;
}

String hex(int n, int d) {
    String s = new String(new char[d]);
    for (int i = d - 1; i >= 0; i--, n >>= 4)
        s = changeCharInString(i,"0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n & 0xF),s);
    return s;
}

String changeCharInString(int pos, char c, String s) {
    return s.substring(0,pos) + c + s.substring(pos+1);
}
```

I've tried this code but it doesn't work. I need to port this over to java for the nes emulator.
in the original code, you can just grab the vertical_blank or sprite_overflow and my code is supposed to do that by inputting the binary number for that position being 1 and it will test to see if the bit is on by zeoring out the surrounding bits and testing to see if it is not-equal to 0. if it is equal to zero, it returns false, else true.

Comment: My recommendation for converting or use code from different languages is by using swig (http://www.swig.org).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, just added it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry but it's not much better. What doesn't work? What did you expect and what happens instead? Help us help you!

Comment: Sorry again, theres a brief explanation of what ive done and what it's supposed to replicate

Comment: Uhm, does this `status|=(v):b?0x00;` even compile?

Comment: oh, must have done a typo when copying over. and it did compile

Comment: Anyway `getStatus` can simply be rewritten as `return status & b != 0`

Comment: oh yeah... oops